# Can the function itself serve as a parameter to another function？

Tags: c, parameters, implicit-conversion, function-declaration

this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getsum(int a,int b){
    return a+b;
}


void fun1(int a,int b,int (*c)(int a,int b)){//Standard writing method
    int sum=getsum(a,b);
    printf("%d\n",sum);
}
void fun2(int a,int b,int c(int a,int b)){//The function itself serves as a parameter
    int sum=getsum(a,b);
    printf("%d\n",sum);
}

int main(){
    int a=1;
    int b=2;
    
    fun1(a,b,getsum);
    fun2(a,b,getsum);
    return 0;
}
```

Both of these functions yield the same result after running
The results are all equal to 3
The c parameter of the first function is written in the standard way, while the second one directly represents the function itself

I just want to know if both of these writing methods are correct

Comment: Since neither `fun1` nor `fun2` uses the `c` argument, the function pointer, it is not clear what you're trying to demonstrate.  However, in `fun2`, what is written as `int c(int a, int b)` is transformed into a pointer to function by the compiler (see C11 [§6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes) ¶8](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p8)), so it means the same as the argument to `fun1`.

Comment: The code in the functions should be more like `int sum = (*c)(a, b);` or `int sum = c(a, b);` — those are equivalent too.

Answer (score 2):

From the C Standard (6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)
Constraints)

> 8 A declaration of a parameter as "function returning type" shall be
> adjusted to "pointer to function returning type", as in 6.3.2.1.

Thus these two function declarations

```
void fun1(int a,int b,int c(int a,int b));
void fun1(int a,int b,int (*c)(int a,int b));
```

declare the same one function. For the first declaration the compiler itself adjusts the parameter having the function type to a parameter having a pointer type to the function type.

In function declarations that are not at the same time its definition you may ommit a parameter name. So the above declarations you may also write like

```
void fun1(int a,int b,int (int a,int b));
void fun1(int a,int b,int (*)(int a,int b));
```

It seems in bodies of your functions you mean

```
int sum=c(a,b);
```

instead of

```
int sum=getsum(a,b);
```

Pay attention to that such an adjustment of a function specifiers does not occur outside function parameter lists.

Consider the following demonstration program.

#include <stdio.h>

```
typedef int Fn( int, int );
typedef int ( *pFn )( int, int );

Fn getsum;

pFn p_getsum = getsum;

int getsum( int a, int b ) {
    return a + b;
}

int main( void )
{
    int x = 1, y = 2;

    printf( "%d + %d = %d\n", x, y, getsum( x, y ) );

    x = y; y = 3;

    printf( "%d + %d = %d\n", x, y, p_getsum( x, y ) );
}
```

In this declaration

```
Fn getsum;
```

the typedef name `Fn` is not adjusted to a pointer type. Here is declared the function `getsum`.